# Customizing layout using hdr in double sided document

Tags: fancyhdr, double-sided, books

I am trying to set custom styles at different places in the document, e.g. first couple of sections no page numbering, while the rest follow common page number and header styling. Running the sample code below i get correct behavior only when the page is even (???). Any help would be appreciated!

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,unicode]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\fancypagestyle{style1}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[CO]{133 Odd}
    \fancyfoot[CE]{133 Even}}
\fancypagestyle{style2}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[CO]{112 Odd}
    \fancyfoot[CE]{113 Even}}
\pagestyle{style1}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{One}
    \pagestyle{style2}
    \chapter{Two}
        text
    \chapter{Three}
    \chapter{Four}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your minimal example is the thing that's showing the problem, and it will show differently in a larger document. The problem is that `\chapter` issues `\thispagestyle{plain}` which you haven't redefined. If you want chapter's first pages to also follow suit, `plain` has to be updated as well.

Comment: By the way, there's no `unicode` documentclass option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `openany` is not used, the chapter starts on the odd numbered page (recto page), this will always use the `plain` page style, not `style1` or `style2`.

If the desired behaviour should prevail for the chapter start page, `plain` page style must be redefined as well. (I used the sample from `style1` here again, since it's not clear what the chapter start page should show.

In order to show more effects, use `\blindtext[10]` to get many full pages, not just `text`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Perhaps?
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[CO]{133 Odd}
  \fancyfoot[CE]{133 Even}
}

\fancypagestyle{style1}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[CO]{133 Odd}
    \fancyfoot[CE]{133 Even}
}
\fancypagestyle{style2}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[CO]{112 Odd}
    \fancyfoot[CE]{113 Even}}
\pagestyle{style1}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\blindtext[10]
\pagestyle{style2}
\chapter{Two}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Three}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{Four}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks for this.
Keeping plain (or calling \thispagestyle right after each \chapter) is useful for different style in chapter pages.

Comment: `\thispagestyle{plain}` might work, but there is no guarantee for that

Comment: Is there a reason for this? I tried it and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`\chapter` also issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`. If you're not interested in that type of style at all, you can update the command `\pagestyle{<style>}` (which you use to change the page style) to also update `plain`; literally copying `<style>` into `plain` (via `\let\ps@plain\ps@<style>`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}   

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule

\makeatletter
\let\oldpagestyle\pagestyle
\renewcommand{\pagestyle}[1]{%
  \oldpagestyle{#1}% Set the page style
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\ps@plain\csname ps@#1\endcsname% Update plain to new page style
}
\makeatother

\fancypagestyle{style1}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[CO]{133 Odd}
  \fancyfoot[CE]{133 Even}}

\fancypagestyle{style2}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[CO]{112 Odd}
  \fancyfoot[CE]{113 Even}}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{style1}
\chapter{One}

\pagestyle{style2}
\chapter{Two}
text

\chapter{Three}

\chapter{Four}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it makes sense to keep it (i did), but of course there are cases you might not. Thank you as well for a clear answer.